# R Shiny renderDataTable() getting an ajax and 404 error

Tags: r, ajax, shiny, datatables, dt

I'm hosting a shiny(free version) app on an ubuntu server

And I'm getting this error message as a popup on my browser:

```
"DataTables warning: table id=DataTables_Table_0 - Ajax error. 
For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7"
```

This is a small snippet of what my server function looks like:

```
####Server ####

server <- function(input, output) {
  
####Heatmap ####
output$all <- renderPlotly({
  
  plot_ly(x = colnames(netmatrix), 
          y = rownames(netmatrix), 
          z = netmatrix, 
          type = "heatmap") %>% layout(xaxis = list(type = 'category'), 
                                       yaxis = list(type = 'category'),
                                       height = 1000)
})


####Table ####
output$table_all <- DT::renderDataTable(
  data.table(summary_table), 
  filter = 'top',
  rownames = FALSE,
  extensions = c("FixedColumns"),
  options = list(searchHighlight = TRUE, 
                 regex = TRUE,
                 scrollX = TRUE,
                 fixedColumns = list(leftColumns = 5)) 
)

} #End of Server
```

When I look at the dev tools console in chrome I see this POST error:

```
my_URI + "/session/86d8f192aa11a9c4eba78560895c26b9/dataobj/table_all?w=&nonce=e01594d12632edd6 404 (Not Found)"
```

I've researched that Ajax error, as well as looked around countless rstudio, github and SO threads, nothing seems to work. I THINK it's some sort of timeout issue in the ajax call because the "Heatmap" is slow to render ~5000x5000 matrix, and when I remove the "Heatmap" component the "Table" loads fine with no errors. I've been scouring options documents for datatable and ajax, but no luck.

Hopefully someone has had this issue or recognizes what's going wrong, any help is appreciated!

EDIT:
Structure of summary table
Removing values and colnames for privacy.

```
str(summary_table)
'data.frame':   589557 obs. of  11 variables:
 $ X1: int 
 $ X2: int  
 $ X3: chr  
 $ X4: chr  
 $ X5: int  
 $ X6: chr  
 $ X7: chr  
 $ X8: chr  
 $ X9: chr  
 $ X10: chr  
 $ X11: chr
```

I did try explicitly doing as.numeric() around the integer columns, as suggested in an old thread on github but that didn't help.

Comment: Could you post `summary_table`?

Comment: How large is `summary_table`?

Comment: I'll make an edit and post the structure of the table. It is large, but it loads fine when I remove the heatmap. So as a single component it  doesn't seem to have an issue.

Comment: And you have already cleared your browser cache?

Comment: @DanielJachetta I have yeah. And because I'm on an enterprise VPN it seems like whenever I work on this at night it looks like its working and then in the day it starts failing again, so there seems to be some latency based issue? I really don't know...I'll probably put a bounty on this soon because I've sunk a few days into this now.

Comment: What if you scaled down your matrix to 25x25, just to see if the heat map is taking too long to load, the table times out?

Comment: I know there is the `browser()` function that will help you debug your shiny code, you could also try the  `withProgress()` function to see if that tell you anything about the shiny app loading

Comment: @DanielJachetta yep works clean and perfect, scaled down my matrix to 100x100 and it takes just a few seconds, and sorry it's actually 2800x2800 not 5k. But yeah, so if nothing else this proves that it's some time based issue. I'm hoping for any easy config solution, I don't want to have to learn async programming just for one error.